# Media Player with MVC pattern

Tags: design-patterns, mvc

Good morning.

I'm developing a media player software with MVC pattern. My question is about the reproduction of media elements.

I think we need 3 software classes in order to do the design. These classes are:

PlayerRegister: A class in Model package that for each user we have a unique instance of it saves media elements reproduced before and the state of actual reproduction (Because the user can't reproduce two files are the same time).

PlayerController: A class in Controller that has all methods to play media elements.
This class interacts with the two other classes.

Video Player: A class in Controller that reproduces the media elements. The kernel of the player.

Is this design of software classes valid? Thank you

Comment: What do you mean by valid? If it works it's valid, so does it work? Do you mean whether it's compatible with MVC?

Comment: Yes, I want to say valid in terms of MVC pattern

Comment: The Video Player also belongs in the Model.